# Android and SQL Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Currently making an app for the very first time, its a massive learning curve for me and the results are satisfying.

So at the moment I have my design all set up, now I need to work on the database side of things.

I have found all the basics to creating tables and adding entries, however I'm a little unsure where I should be inserting this code.

My queries are:

=> Does the code for creating the database tables, inserting/editing/deleting data need to have its own class, separate classes or is it all be done in the class of the 'Form' I have created.

=> How do you connect to the DB so I can call the results, does this need its own class also for showing the entries or can this be done on my 'Entries' class.

Working with android studio, if anyone can give me a better understanding would be much appreciated.

Comment: that's software and object orientation architecture. Nothing special related specific to Android.

Comment: Better to give specific code that you have tried/displays what your app is currently set up. There are many ways to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> => Does the code for creating the database tables, inserting/editing/deleting data need to have its own class, separate classes or is it all be done in the class of the 'Form' I have created.
>
> => How do you connect to the DB so I can call the results, does this need its own class also for showing the entries or can this be done on my 'Entries' class.

I'll answer both of those at the same time:

- You don't actually need to make all of the code for the database usage on a separate class, it can be done in the same Android extended class you are working on. Though I highly reccomend you to make a separate one to keep things organized and easier to find.
- Basically all of your queries will be managed with a `Cursor` class, that works pretty much like an iterator, no secrets here.

I would suggest that you take a look at **MVC Architecture** to help you organize your code and make it as clean as an OxiCelan ad.

Answer (score 1):

Its a pretty easy thing to do. You need to create a class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper. In the default constructor you need to pass a few values.

Take this for example:

```
public DBHandler (Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
```

Define a final field DATABASE_NAME and DATABASE_VERSION in the class.

Override onCreate and onUpgrade methods and you are good to go.

onUpgrade method:

```
@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ACCOUNT);
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

In the onCreate you need to give the query to create your table. Create the query as a string and just use execSQL on SQLiteDatabase object to execute that query.